# How can I read a string from command line?

Tags: c#, string, command-line-interface

So I have a set of files that I am trying to get a word count on. I am trying to enter a file path in command line and then run an executable on them to see the word count in the command line.

Code for word count that I have:

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllText(@"path"/*I want the path here to be read from what I enter in the command line.*/).Split(' ');
```

Then to find the word count:

```
int wordcount= words.length-1;
```

I then want wordcount to be returned to me in the commandline. So, to reiterate, I need to be able to enter a file into the command line, run the word counting exe on it, and return the wordcount number to the commandline. This is a homework assignment for me, so if possible it would be great if you could refer me to a place to understand how to do this if you answer. Thanks in advance to anyone that tries to help.

Comment: What specifically do you not know how to do? Do you know how to read in from the console, do you know how to write out to the console?

Comment: Use either `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` or the `args` parameter to your main method to get arguments from the command line.

Comment: @Scott both. I can open them command prompt and run a exe, but I don't know how to read and write to the command prompt.

Comment: Are you expecting to do `yourprogram.exe countThisFile.txt` as a single line on the command line or do you expect to do `yourprogram.exe` then once the program starts do `countThisFile.txt` from inside the program?

Comment: @scot single line on the command line if I can. I want to enter the text file path, then enter the exe, and get the word count back to me in the command line.

Comment: Commands on the command line don't work like that, you have to enter the exe then enter the text file path

Comment: @scott So I could do something like:

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write to the console like this :

```
var fileName = Console.ReadLine()

...

Console.WriteLine(wordcount);
```

also please note , fileName should be full path to the locaiton file

Comment: The line *"I am trying to enter a file path in command line and then run an executable on them..."* makes me believe `Console.ReadLine()` is *not* what the OP wants, he wants command line args.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this. There are a variety of other things one can do with the `Console` class, including writing lines and reading keys.

Comment: The line *"I am trying to enter a file path in command line and then run an executable on them..."* makes me believe this is *not* what the OP wants, he wants command line args.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I interpret this same phrase as not expecting a command line argument, but expecting interactive input on the console, *especially* since this is a homework assignment and most will be running directly from Visual Studio with no arguments.